# What legal rights do Dave Grohl and Krist Novoselic have over how Nirvana's music is used?

Tags: music-business

Do Dave Grohl and Krist Novoselic have any legal rights in regard to the licensing of Nirvana's music?

I understand they have been in legal battles with Courtney Love over Nirvana's back catalogue and I  had heard that Courtney Love sold 25% of her share for $50,000,000.

What legal rights would Dave Grohl and Krist Novoselic have if she decided to sell her share to someone they deemed unsuitable say the Coca - Cola company for example? Even though Kurt Cobain composed most of Nirvana's music, they are all credited as writing some songs including "Smells Like Teen Spirit", what rights would they have if the song was used in a Coke ad?

I know that Courtney Love has said that she wants to preserve Kurt's legacy, but I wouldn't put anything past her, if she was old and broke, she'd sell out for sure!

Comment: Legal opinions are not the remit of any SE site except [Law](http://law.stackexchange.com) & even they wouldn't be able to answer this. If it's in court, then no-one yet knows the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't aware, hey if you don't ask you don't learn.